# :tabonly does not close all unmodified tabs if there is a modified tab in the way

Tags: command-line, tabbed-user-interface

Create some test files,

```
touch a b c d
```

and open each in a tab,

```
vim -p a b c d
```

Modify file `b`. Go to tab `c` and issue `:tabonly`.

- Expected behavior: `a` and `d` tabs are closed. `b` is not closed because
  it is in modified state.
- Actual behavior: Only `a` tab is closed.

If the same is attempted by issuing `:only` command with windows, it works as expected.

Is the actual behavior documented or should it be considered a bug?
Apparently `:help :tabonly` does not specify it.

Is there "the proper command"
to get all unmodified tabs closed without raising dialogs, even
if some other modified tab is in the way?
Or some less verbose alternative to `:tabd :sil :q`?

Comment: use `:set hidden`

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Thank you for the suggestion, but that would lead to the closure of modified tabs. I am not really using `only` commands to have just one tab/window in view, but rather because they are a handy way of getting rid of the tabs/windows that I am already done with.

Comment: Between tab use and the implication that `hidden` is not enabled, it sounds like you are not availing yourself of the buffer-centric workflow that so many of us moved to at some point and now wouldn't move away from for all the tea in China. Am I telling you something you've already heard a hundred times? :) If so, don't take offense, it's just really that good and I try to convince everyone. If you need any guidance on that let us know. Cheers.

Comment: @BLayer I use tabs because I like to see the open files in a eye-blink and because I find `gt` handy. I am a recent Vim user and probably have a handful naive approaches, apparently this use of 1tab-1file is also one of them. I take no offense at all if someone points better alternatives. On the contrary, if you say experienced users are usually quite fond of the buffer workflow, a big, big thanks for giving me a nudge in that direction! Especially because Vim is deep, those nudges are really helpful and your suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: Two links relevant to BL's comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26708822/why-do-vim-experts-prefer-buffers-over-tabs and https://joshldavis.com/2014/04/05/vim-tab-madness-buffers-vs-tabs/. As a new vim user, I too have taken the tab route.

Comment: Thanks, DK, those are perfect. You saved me time I'd need to look them up.  @Quasímodo I'd read the first two answers and accompanying comments of the first link and all of the second link. Why the comments? Because you might find handy shortcuts and the like (e.g. this super handy mapping: `nnoremap <leader>b :ls<CR>:b`). Another useful post though not about tabs vs buffers is the classic "your problem with vim is you don't grok vi" answer here: [What is your most productive shortcut with Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1218390)  :)

Comment: Thank you both DK Bose and B Layer for your guidance! This community is awesome. I am certainly going to read those.