# How to open two new empty buffers in two separate windows?

Tags: buffers, terminal

This is a follow-up question from this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4478111/3398271) and [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4478193/3398271).

Is it possible, and if so how, to **open two (or more) new empty buffers in Vim (without associating them to a file), such that they both take on the whole window**? (And such that you can move among them with `:bprev / :bnext`, i.e. in the exact same way, as if you did `:badd <filename>`?)

In other words, I don't want splits and tabs, just "normal" buffers.

I tried `:enew` twice, but the second buffer discards the first one...

**To put it in a different way**: what is the Vim equivalent of opening more new empty files in a GUI text editor?

**Still in other words**

I want something like this:

```
:ls
  1 #a   "[No Name]"                    line 0
  2 %a   "[No Name]"                    line 1
```

But `1` and `2` should NOT be in split window, both should have their own window, taking up the full screen. (Just as if I did `:badd <filename>`. Pity that `:badd` without arguments does not open a new empty window.)

Comment: how about `:enew|:new`?

Comment: @BLayer, Christian : I tried both now, but the two buffers are a _split_ in the same window. Maybe the right question is, how to have two new empty _windows_? I'll edit the title accordingly.

Comment: I probably used the terms incorrectly. Anyway `:set hidden` was the solution I needed. After that, I can just do many `:enew`'s (as long as I add some content), and they are not lost. I am using terminal vim, in case that matters. (Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but `:new` still opens the new buffer for me in a split, i.e. the screen area is split into two equal spaces for the two empty buffers, they don't take up the whole screen.)

Comment: What would still be nice to have, is doing `:enew` many times (without adding any content) and ending up with many empty buffers (or windows?). Let's say the equivalent of doing `:badd file1`, `:badd file2`, `:badd file3`, but with empty screens.

Comment: @Attilio Understanding that someone could post an alternative, possibly better for you, answer later, does my suggestion meet your needs? If so, I'll add a proper answer so no one need wade through all these comments (which we can then delete).

Comment: @BLayer: yes the one with `:set hidden` does what I need, it would be worth an answer.

Comment: `:exe "hide b" bufadd("")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing's first, let's make sure our definitions are in sync. Per, [`:h window`](https://vimhelp.org/windows.txt.html#window):

- A buffer is the in-memory text of a file.
- A window is a viewport on a buffer.
- (And for the sake of completeness) A tab page is a collection of windows.

Above these things are your terminal window or your GUI window which contain Vim. Vim has no direct control over these kinds of windows and we will not refer to them beyond this point.

Second, there's an important setting that will impact how things work: [`'hidden'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27hidden%27). By default this is disabled and when that's the case one of its effects is to delete empty buffers if they go out of view. That will cramp our style so do `:set hidden`.

As an aside, many people can't live without enabling this because doing so allows a much better, buffer-centric workflow than you can get otherwise. There are volumes written about this and, coincidentally, in the last couple days I was proselytizing about it here [in some comments](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/26760/tabonly-does-not-close-all-unmodified-tabs-if-there-is-a-modified-tab-in-the-wa#comment47686_26760).

Anyways, back on topic, now that we have `'hidden'` enabled we just need to run one or two basic commands. First, `:new`. This will open a new window (a "split") and it will contain a fresh, new buffer. If your preference is one window per buffer that's all you need. You can keep running it until you are sated.

TIP: after the first `:new` use  Normal mode command `@:` to repeat it. Precede with a number to repeat it that many times.

On the other hand, if you only want a single window with all but the original buffer hidden (and accessible with, for example, `:bnext`) then simply enter a second command `:close`. Repeat `:new` then `:close` as often as needed. Better yet, use `:new | close`. Then you can use the same tip as above `[count]@:`.

That's pretty much it.

(Note: `:enew` will open a fresh, new buffer without opening a split but it will clobber any fresh, new buffer already opened in the same window. You'd have to modify the existing buffer to avoid this.)

Comment: Thanks, the `:new | close` part (together with `:set hidden`) does _exactly_ what I need.

Comment: @Attilio Awesome. Glad to hear it.

Answer (score 2):

`:hide enew` is what the OP asked for.

This will hide - not destroy - whatever is in the current buffer of the current window and open a new `NO-FILE` in-memory-only buffer.

Comment: Probably worth noting that this will work even if the `'hidden'` option is *not* set.

Comment: Right, it will set 'hidden' even if it was not set before. :he :hide